# Suffixes to certain words

Tags: suffixes

Can -ed, -ing and -tion be added to the words *positive*, *negative* and *advise*? What rules would explain this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to ELU.  As you have written it, it is not possible to answer your question. First, it is not clear whether "-i g" is a mistype for "ing":  if so please edit.  Second, assuming I am right in my guess, it seems as if you are asking whether you are asking whether three nouns can be given endings that belong to verbs.  But in that case, you may have mistyped "advise", which is a verb and meant to write 'advice', which is the noun.  Third, It is not clear if you mean to ask whether "positive" can change to "positived", "positiving" and "position" or why you want to know this,

Comment: "Advise" is a verb, and has tenses.  "Positive" and "negative" are not verbs (though people do verb them from time to time).

Answer (score 1):

No. The suffixes you mention do not apply to *positive* and *negative*, and the only suffix of the ones you mention which can be added to the word *advise* is *-d*. (*-s* can also be added to advise, as in "He *advises* me on matters of diplomacy.")

There are a number of rules governing the adding of suffixes to words, but some adjectives, including *positive* and *negative*, take no suffixes besides *-s*, *-ly*, and  *-ity*. Hence,

- There were more *positives* [i.e., positive votes] than *negatives*.
- She responded *negatively* to the the editorial she read in the Op-Ed pages of the newspaper.
- He was discouraged by the obvious *negativity* of the voters in the election.

By doing so, however, the words are changed from adjectives to nouns, or to an adverb (viz., *negatively*). Hence,

- He was discouraged by the number of *negatively* skewed votes in the election.

The suffix *-ing* is a suffix which changes verbs to either gerunds, verbal nouns, or present participles, as in

- *Advising* is my favorite responsibility in my job description.
- *The advising* of students is not the responsibility of teachers. (Note: verbal nouns are preceded by *the* and followed by *of*.)
- He was seen *walking* down Main Street.

In short, there are many rules governing suffixes, and I have barely scratched the surface of those rules.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, rhetorican

Comment: So as a conclusion: there are such forms as advised and advising but no more from my question above.

Comment: @kinga: Correct, but you can add -s to advise, which gives you advises.The noun form (viz., advice), however, does not take any of your suffixes, nor does it take an -s. Don

Comment: Yes, thanks we were fine with understanding the -s added. You saved a full homework here, my son is delighted. We were so unsure. Thanks again